# Cannot establish connection with RMI Registry on a remote server

Tags: java, azure, client-server, rmi, firewall

Currently I'm trying to start a java server using RMI on a remote machine. Server seem to start, but I can't invoke its methods on a client.
On a client I get an exception which looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.0.0.6; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
```

This is my RMI Server constructor:

```
    private RmiServer(String address, int port) throws RemoteException, SQLException, MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("This address = " + address + ", Port = " + port);
        Registry registry;
        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(PORT);
        } catch (RemoteException e)
        {
            registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(PORT);
        }
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", address);
        try {
            registry.bind(REGISTRY_NAME, this);
            Naming.bind(address, this);
        }
        catch (AlreadyBoundException e)
        {
            registry.rebind(REGISTRY_NAME, this);
            Naming.rebind(address, this);
        }
        ...
    }
```

And this is my client code:

```
    static public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT);
            rmiServer = (ReceiveMessageInterface) registry.lookup(REGISTRY_NAME);
        } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            isServerOK = false;
        }
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        boolean isAuthenticated = false;
        int pin;
        String cardNumber;
        SessionInfo session = null;
        if (isServerOK) {
            while (true) {
                if (!isAuthenticated) {
                    System.out.println("Welcome Customer to HDFC Bank ATM : \nPlease enter your card number: ");
                    cardNumber = reader.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter your PIN: ");
                    pin = reader.nextInt();
                    String cardHolderName = rmiServer.verifyPIN(cardNumber, pin);
                    ...
                }
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

I start server with this string:

```
java -cp flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:. -Djava.security.policy=java.security.AllPermission kmalfa.RmiServer
```

My server runs on linux virtual machine. I use Microsoft Azure service. I turned off firewall on my client and on virtual machine. I allowed all incoming connections in Azure settings for testing purposes and it doesn't help.
What could be the problem?

Comment: The only possible solution left is to set my codebase, but I'm not sure how to properly set it... Maybe, someone could explain it to me in details?..

Comment: No it isn't. You should *remove* the security manager. You don't need it. This problem is item A.1 on the RMI FAQ..

Comment: @user207421 I tried to use solution from RMI FAQ item A.1, but it didn't help me. I still get the exception.

Comment: If you stil get the same exception with the same IP address shown, you didn't do it right.

Comment: @user207421 Could you explain how do I need to bind registry? I updated the code in my question. Do I set up the registry correctly? How do I need to use Naming.bind on server and Naming.lookup on client exactly?

Comment: You're doing it right, but the binds and lookups via the address are pointless. Just bind and lookup via the name. You need to set `java.rmi.server.hostname` at the server JVM before any of that, and before creating the registry and the remote object. In other words before this constructor runs.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you, it started working. I had to set java.rmi.server.hostname not in RmiServer constructor but before. Now it's working. Thank you very much!

Comment: The reason is that as your object extends `UnicastRemoteObject`, it is auto-exported when the (implicit) `super()` call runs in the constructor, which is the point at which `java.rmi.server.hostname` is interrogated (if it hasn't already been).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Just had to call

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", address);
```

Not in *RmiServer* constructor, but before calling it, at the beginning of *main*